# Convert field names to lower case using miller

Tags: unix-text-processing, miller

I would like to use miller (mlr) to convert column names to lower case. The closest I get is using the `rename` verb with a regular expression. `\L` should change the case, but instead the the column names are getting prefixed by `"\L"`.

I'm using macOS Catalina and miller 5.10.0

```
echo -e 'A,B,C\n1,2,3' | mlr --csv --opprint rename -r '(.*),\L\1'
```

prints

```
\LA \LB \LC
1   2   3
```

But I would like it to print

```
a b c
1 2 3
```

Comment: Did you try my solutions?

Comment: These both work, thank you! It appears that miller's DSL is very powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two examples ways:

```
echo -e 'A,B,C\n1,2,3' | mlr --csv put '
  map inrec = $*;
  $* = {};
  for (oldkey, value in inrec) {
    newkey = tolower(oldkey);
    $[newkey] = value;
  }
'
```

or

```
echo -e 'A,B,C\n1,2,3' | mlr --csv -N put -S 'if (NR == 1) {for (k in $*) {$[k] = tolower($[k])}}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, standard tools are easier to use:

```bash
echo -e 'A,B,C\n1,2,3' | awk 'NR == 1 { $0 = tolower($0) } 1'
```

---

**UPDATE**

with Miller:

```bash
echo -e 'A,B,C\n1,2,3' |
mlr --csv -N put 'NR == 1 {for (k,v in $*) {$[k] = tolower(v)}}'
```

Comment: @Favadona This is an excellent solution and probably what I will use in the future since it is so simple. The original questions asked for an answer using miller so I will leave aborruso's answer as the accepted answer.